# docker image stuck at pulling fs layer

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-registry

We are using a self hosted version of Jfrog Artifactory and for some reason Artifactory went down and which we were able to resolve by restarting the server.  After reboot everything seemed to come back up correctly, however we realized that anything using a particular layer ddad3d7c1e96 which is actually pulling down alpine 3.11.11 from docker hub was now getting stuck at pulling fs layer and would just sit and keep retrying.

We tried "Zapping Caches" and running the maintenance option for Garbage Collection/Unused artifacts but we were still unable to download any image that had this particular layer.

Is it possible that this layer was somehow cached in artifactory and ended up being corrupted.  We were also looked through the filestore and were unsuccessful in finding the blob.

After a few days, the issue resolved itself and images can now be pulled but we are now left without an explanation...

Does anyone have an idea of what could have happened and how we can clear out cached parent images which are not directly in our container registry but pulled from docker hub or another registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ran into a similar issue - zapping caches worked for us however it took some time to complete